# Epiphany shows Oops Something went wrong while displaying this page

Tags: epiphany, crash

I have just installed Elementary OS 5.1 and, while browsing the Internet, all tabs in Epiphany show "Oops Something went wrong while displaying this page".

After refreshing it was fine for a moment. I then went on to close the browser and had a look around the OS only to realise that I needed something from Amazon and went to https://www.amazon.co.uk, but I cannot load the site.

What I see is — for about 1-2 seconds — the Amazon front page and then the white page with the “Oops - Something went wrong while displaying this page” error.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Firefox is rock solid.

Ping looks good:

```
--- amazon.co.uk ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.708/29.337/41.284/4.366 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

That means the web process has crashed. To diagnose crashes, developers need to see a backtrace of the crash taken with gdb. Sadly, I believe elementary doesn't have any tools to report the crash automatically, so you will have to learn to do it manually if you want the developers to look at the issue. After verifying that you are running the latest stable version of WebKitGTK (currently 2.26.2), [get a quality backtrace](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces) for the crash using `coredumpctl gdb` (installing any required debuginfo), then report it on [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org) against the WebKitGTK component. Prefix the bug title with [GTK].

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to try another browser - firefox and chromium can be easily isntalled. I had such problems with Epiphany also but did not found the reason - it was more easy for me to change the web browser.